# How to find value from xml based on tag using JavaScript function in Karate

Tags: javascript, karate

If I want to get the value of an element in karate, I can use "response //RecordA/RecordSequence".  How to get the same value in a function using below approach. I have tried .getElementsByTagName, .find and karate.get but it does not work under a function to find a specific value based on tag. Any help appreciated to find value based on tag under function.

```
Background:
* def myxml =
      """
        function(tags) 
         {
          var xmlValue= tags.getElementsByTagName("RecordA"); // Getting error as 
                                                              .getElementsByTagName is not supported
          
          return xmlValue;
        }        
      """ 

Given request 
when soap action ''
Then status 200
* def resxml = response
* def myresult= myxml(resxml)
And assert result100 = '<expected_desc1>'|| result100 = '<expected_desc1>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
* def temp = <root><hello>world</hello></root>
* def fun = function(data){ return karate.xmlPath(data, '/root/hello') }
* def val = fun(temp)
* match val == 'world'
```

Comment: Thanks. I enhanced and used in a case where I expect different tag for different environment.

Comment: I see error while try to put this in condition to check if the first tag is not available, take value from another tag. Getting error javascript evaluation failed: myxml(resxml), myxml(resxml).

* def temp = response
*def tempxml = fun(data)
* def fun = function(data)
{ 
var temp = karate.xmlPath(data, '/Envelope/Body/OrderResponse/RecordF')  
        if ( temp != null){var xmlValue =  karate.xmlPath(data,'/Envelope/Body/OrderResponse/RecordF/MissInfo')}
else{var xmlValue =  karate.xmlPath(data,'/Envelope/Body/OrderResponse/RecordG/MissInfo')}
return xmlPath;
}
* def val = fun(temp)

Comment: @Srikanta ask a new question if needed and keep it mcve: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example